# Dealing with dependency injection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js

So, I have this situation when I'd like to know how I should deal with a thing that I think it's pretty common among (at least) Backbone developers.

Considering I have this code:

```javascript
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend();

var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model : Book
});

var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({ render: function(){ return this; } });

var BooksView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.collection.on('add', this.addItem, this );
  },

  addItem: function(){
    var book = new BookView(); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    this.$el.append( book.render().$el );
  },
});

var book = new BookView({ collection: new Books() });
```

How I could deal with the `new BookView` part?

One way I was thinking was to use a factory:

```
function BookViewFactory() {
  this.getBook = new BookView();
}
```

And pass an instance of this on `BookView` instantiantion:

```
var book = new BookView({ collection: new Books(), bookView : new BookViewFactory() });
```

Then, on the `addItem` method I would call `this.bookView.getBook()`.

Is this the right thing to do? There is some other way I am missing?

Thanks!

*Please don't suggest me any dependency libraries (browserify, module, AMD, etc) just yet, because I'm at the stage when I want to learn how stuff works.*

Comment: I'm a little confused by your example - when you instantiate a new BookView, you set a property on that view that is a new instance of the same BookView? And getBook is called inside BookViewFactory,not on BookView objects.

Comment: Heh, you are right, it was just a typo :) The object that is passed is actually an instance of `BookViewFactory`. Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `var book = new BookView()`? You don't want `BooksView` to depend on `BookView` even though it really does?

Comment: @muistooshort : it's impossible to unit test.

Comment: If you namespace everything (`app.BookView` instead of just `BookView`) then it becomes easier to stub things for testing, no? You want to do that anyway in a real app.